# Why additional variables are created in the amplify database?

Tags: ios, swiftui, cocoapods, aws-amplify

```
public struct CartProduct: Model {
  public let id: String
  public var cart: Cart?
  public var product: Product?
  public var cardId: String?
  public var createdAt: Temporal.DateTime?
  public var updatedAt: Temporal.DateTime?
  public var cartProductCartId: String?
  public var cartProductProductId: String?
```

[image]

additional variables are :

```
  public var createdAt: Temporal.DateTime?
  public var updatedAt: Temporal.DateTime?
  public var cartProductCartId: String?
  public var cartProductProductId: String?
```

Answer (score 0):

`createdAt`, `updatedAt` is automatically managed by `AppSync`(which you can also update as well - *if you specify in the create/update operation*). For other two additional fields, It's because it has connection with 2 model. You can think of it as foreign key in Relational Database.

So when creating `CartProduct`, you should add `cardId`, and `productId`, so that when getting/fetching `CardProduct` items, AppSync will get corresponding `Card` and `Product` data.

Your expected `ProductType` query results' item would be like this:

```
{
  id,
  cart,
  product,
  cardId,
  createdAt,
  updatedAt,
  cartProductCardId
  cartProductCart: {
    id
  }
  cartProductProductId,
  cartProductProduct: {
    id,
    name,
    price
  }
}
```

Here's how you can create similar models using `GraphQL Schema`.

```
type CardProduct @model {
  id: ID!
  cardId: ID
  card: Card @connection(fields: ["cardId"])
  productId: ID
  product: Product @connection(fields: ["productId"])
}

type Product @model {
  id
}

type Card @model {
  id
}
```